# Young's experiment but with reflection from two thin wires?

Tags: optics

Is it possible to shine a laser beam on two thin metal wires that are really close to each other and observe a **reflection** interference pattern? I would like to confirm that the pattern is the same as the one obtained by transmission through a double slit, thus indirectly confirming Huygens' principle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I use guitar strings all the time to do these experiments. Youngs original experiment was with one human hair. My guitar strings all have different gauges and the experiments work perfectly for the fringe pattern spacings. It just depends on the wavelength of laser light, the distance from the wire to the Wall and the gauge of the wire.

Comment: And how about reflecting laser light over two wires? Can you create an interference pattern?

Comment: You can create a fringe pattern just by shining the laser on one wire. The light passes both edges of the wire and creates the pattern on the screen beyond. If you use two wires the light will pass four edges on the way to the screen and also create a pattern. The pattern will be affected by how far apart the wires are apart. If you use many evenly spaced wires you will have a diffraction grading.

Comment: I don't want to create a fringe pattern behind the wire(s). I would like coherent light to scatter on both wires and create an interference pattern on the same side as is the laser. I want the wires to become two sources in phase and thus show that the pattern obtained is the same as the one we get through two slits (Huygens' principle).

Comment: The problem is you still need a detection screen for the pattern to form on. If it's on the original source side between the laser and the wires then it would be blocking the laser from ever even getting to the wires in the first place.

Comment: I would be satisfied to observe first and second orders, so screen could be behind laser.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to get any orders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46551/discussion-between-courno-and-bill-alsept).

Comment: I'm on my cell phone right now but go ahead start the discussion I'll try to find it later thanks